# Commercial usage of Bitbucket academic plan?

Tags: bitbucket

I can't find answer to this question anywhere.

Just like in title: It is possible to use Bitbucket academic plan for commercial purposes since it is nowhere prohibited?

Answer (score 0):

I was wandering the same so I asked them and the answer is NO. You can not use academic licence for commercial purpose but that was somewhere to be expected. Here is the [link](https://support.atlassian.com/servicedesk/customer/portal/5/CA-168534) to the question for verification.